# Is there a way to loop through a range of cells and assign each value in the cell to different variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Range ("A1:A"+finalRow), where finalRow is the last row at the "A" column and his value change randomly.

I need to extract each value from the range and assign each value to a different variable name, e.g. var1, var2, ..., var+finalRow.

In this case, I have 20 cells/values, part of my code as follows:

```vb
For y = 1 To finalRow
    
    If finalRow = 20 Then
        res1 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos1 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
        res2 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos2 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
        res3 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos3 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
        '...
        res20 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos20 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
        
    ElseIf finalRow = 19 Then
        res1 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos1 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
        res2 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos2 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
        res3 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos3 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
        '...
        res19 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos19 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
        
    ElseIf finalRow = 18 Then
        '...
    
    ElseIf finalRow = 1 Then
        res1 = Range("A" + y).Value
        pos1 = Range(1, y + 4).Address
    
Next y
```

Is it possible to do the range tour without creating a lot of code?

Comment: Use an array... that many variables is a code smell.

Comment: Have  a look at [arrays](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-range-cells/#Reading_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array)

Comment: Try using a dictionary. The cell address will be the key and the cell value the item.

Comment: You can assign the values /addresses from a range of cells to a variant array (e.g. Dim myValues as Variant, myAddresses as Variant and then myValues = <sheet qualifier>.Range("A1:A"+finalrow).value etc.  Because you are using two arrays you will need to iterate over those arrays using LBound and UBound.

Comment: Can you try explaining the meaning of "what I need"? You maybe will receive some code to cover it. Otherwise, being not familiar with arrays or dictionaries it is more difficult to understand our suggestion, I think.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of the result, e.g. `1. E1`|`2, E2`|`3, E3`... I am interested in the `pos` part since you are using 'y + 4' in a wrong range assignement: `... = Range(1, y + 4).Address`. I understand the values for which I used 1, 2 and 3, but the addresses are not clear.

Comment: BigBen, Storax and freeflow, thanks for your opinions. I'm beginner with the use of arrays, and you know it with my example code. However, I will review more information about arrays variables, because I need cut my code as in this situation.
FaneDuru, the explanation about what I need, actually I just need work correctly with array variables for cut my VBA codes and that can be seen better.

Comment: VBasic2008, actually I used the address function for take the column reference "y" and add 4 positions since the present selection. I.e., if y = 1, the cell reference Range(1,1+4) is the same reference that Range("E1"). Moreover, that reference I use in another part of my code, which I didn't show it in this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using arrays to simplify your code, you could do this (of course the explanatory comments can be omitted!!):

```
Dim Res(1 To 20) As Variant '-- Amended per VBasic2008's helpful suggestion
Dim Pos(1 To 20) As Variant
Dim y As Long

'-- NOTE: It's good practice to explicitly reference your workbook and worksheet.
'-- If you specify just "Range" without qualification, it will refer to whichever
'-- worksheet is active, and if you have more than one Excel workbook open,
'-- you could get unexpected results if you switch between workbooks. 
'-- "ThisWorkbook" ensures you are referring to the workbook that's running this code.
'-- Sheets("Sheet1") ensures you are dealing with the named sheet only. Now ".Range" 
'-- (don't omit the "."!!) can only refer to the cells in ThisWorkbook on Sheet1.

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For y = 1 To finalRow
        Res(y) = .Range("A" & y).Value
        Pos(y) = .Cells(1, y + 4).Address
    Next
End With
```

Now wherever you currently use Res1, Res2, etc. you would refer to Res(1), Res(2)... (i.e. the array element) instead.

Two further points:
You need to use "&" rather than "+" in your Range reference.
Your .Range(1, y + 4) won't work.  Assuming you are trying to use a Row/Col combination here, it needs to be .Cells(1, y + 4).

Comment: You have defined the arrays to 22 (0-21) elements and you're not using the first (0) and the last (21), when you could have defined them e.g. like this: `Dim Res(1 To 20) As Variant`. Additionallyl, the arrays should be defined after `finalRow` is set e.g. `Dim Res(1 To finalRow) As Variant`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Good points both. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: @VBasic2008 In terms of finalRow, it seems to be defined elsewhere, so I'm removing the definition in this code segment.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much, VBasic2008, for your explanation and your suggestion.
Overall, thanks for the very good explanation, user9601310, that's what I need, a form to reduce my code with much variables.
Just a final question for all partners in this workspace. As I said before, I'm an beginner user with VBA, but, why you use the dot "." before a property? In this case, ".Range" or ".Cells". If I write the code as you present it to me, VBA show me error about a invalid reference.
Again, thanks for all!

Comment: The .Range and .Cells are (should be!!) valid within the scope of the **With ... End with**. If you don't have those, then the dot won't work. In essence, using With ... enables you to refer to the properties without having to repeat "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")". Otherwise you'd have to specify ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells, etc. In this particular example, with just two places where the dot notation is used, you could arguably do without the "With" and fully qualify each line. When there are longer blocks of code, it's much more useful.

Comment: I understand, and got it!
Again, thank you very much for the help, user9601310.

Answer (score 1):

### A Mountain of Variables

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AMoutainOfVariables()

    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const ColumnString As String = "A"
    Const ColumnOffset As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet ' Better qualify with e.g. wb.worksheets("Sheet1").
    
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    FinalRow = 20
    
    ' Get values and cell addresses into an array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = getColumnVnA(ws, ColumnString, FirstRow, FinalRow, , ColumnOffset)
    
    ' Now instead of
    '    res1, pos1, res2, pos2 ... you use:
    '    Data(1, 1), Data(1, 2), Data(2, 1), Data(2, 2) ...
    
    ' Now you can do something like the following.
    
    ' Write values and cell addresses to the Immediate window (CTRL+G).
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Debug.Print Data(i, 1), Data(i, 2)
    Next i

End Sub
    
' Writes the values and cell addresses of a one-column range, defined by its
' column string and first and last row numbers, to a 2D one-based two-column
' array.
Function getColumnVnA(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                      Optional ByVal ColumnString As String = "A", _
                      Optional ByVal FirstRowNumber As Long = 1, _
                      Optional ByVal LastRowNumber As Long = 1, _
                      Optional ByVal RowOffset As Long = 0, _
                      Optional ByVal ColumnOffset As Long = 0) _
         As Variant
    ' Calculate Number of Rows ('NoR').
    Dim NoR As Long
    NoR = LastRowNumber - FirstRowNumber + 1
    ' Write values from One-Column Range to Data Array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant
    If NoR > 1 Then
    ' One-Column Range contains multiple cells.
        Data = Sheet.Cells(FirstRowNumber, ColumnString).Resize(NoR).Value
    Else
    ' One-Column Range contains one cell only.
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data = Sheet.Cells(FirstRowNumber, ColumnString).Value
    End If
    ' 'Add' a column to Data Array.
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To NoR, 1 To 2)
    ' Write cell addresses to 2nd column of Data Array.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To NoR
        Data(i, 2) = Sheet.Range(ColumnString & CStr(i + FirstRowNumber - 1)) _
                          .Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset).Address(0, 0)
    Next i
    ' Write result.
    getColumnVnA = Data
End Function
```